Styling html and css
I know basically nothing about html and css, but I have a docusaurus site in which I would like a card, similar to this: https://necrovox.org/docs/gangs/gang-lists/house-escher/#gang-queen-leader. I've looked in the inspector, but not sure how I should use the code to get it right.

I think I managed it myself, but feel free to improve:


.fighter-card {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.card-header {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.fighter-type {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.credits {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.credits span {
  font-size: 8px;
  display: block;
}

.card-body {
  padding: 15px;
}

.stats-table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.stats-table th, .stats-table td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
}

.stats-table th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.stats-table th.mental-stat,
.stats-table td.mental-stat {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.stats-table th:nth-child(9),
.stats-table td:nth-child(9) {
  border-left: 2px solid #999;
}

.info p {
  margin: 5px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.info strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
<div class="fighter-card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h2 class="fighter-type">GANG QUEEN (LEADER)</h2>
    <div class="credits">125 <span>CREDITS</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <table class="stats-table">
      <tr>
        <th>M</th>
        <th>WS</th>
        <th>BS</th>
        <th>S</th>
        <th>T</th>
        <th>W</th>
        <th>I</th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th class="mental-stat">Ld</th>
        <th class="mental-stat">Cl</th>
        <th class="mental-stat">Wil</th>
        <th class="mental-stat">Int</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5"</td>
        <td>3+</td>
        <td>3+</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2+</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td class="mental-stat">5+</td>
        <td class="mental-stat">5+</td>
        <td class="mental-stat">6+</td>
        <td class="mental-stat">7+</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="info">
      <p><strong>Skills:</strong> 1 Primary (custom).</p>
      <p><strong>Restrictions:</strong> None.</p>
      <p><strong>Special Rules:</strong> Gang Leader, Gang Hierarchy (Leader), Tools of the Trade, Group Activation (2).</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



